# Создание рамки вокруг меню

Tags: css

http://joxi.ru/823BopeTJ8ORQm

Есть такая рамка вокруг меню, проблема заключается в том, что у ссылки "Меню" нет фона, чтобы перекрыть рамку, не хотелось бы ее вырезать и вставлять через background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body{
 background: url(http://ss.sport-express.ru/userfiles/materials/125/1252008/large.jpg) no-repeat center top;
 background-size: cover;
}

.menu{
 color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.7);
 border-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="menu">
    <legend>Menu</legend>

    <div class="menu__list">Content</div>

</fieldset>
```